# NewLine Characters in a textArea

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, textarea, encode

Here is my code

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Sites()
{
    var viewModel =  new ViewModel();
    viewModel.currentSite.genComments =HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Some string that</br>\r\n looks like this<br/>"); 
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(v => v.currentSite.gencomments, Model.currentSite.gencomments, "gencomments")
```

I get an error saying that there are invalid characters in the path.
Any ideas or suggestions

Comment: Why are you doing Html.Encode before saving to the database? Where are those `<br/>` tags coming from? When a user enters something into a textarea there are no `<br/>` and there shouldn't be any. Only new lines - `\r\n`. You shouldn't be encoding anything nor introducing any `<br/>` tags before saving to the database. Store the user input as is. And then display it as-is.

Comment: I am not doing Html.Encode before saving, I do it after retrieving from the database. The </br> tags are included in the text from the text area and saved to the database because we show these notes in a tooltip, so its nice to have them formatted in HTML

Comment: how exactly are you displaying the retrieved value from the database on your view? Are you using a textarea or are you displaying it in a div or something. Please show more code because your question is extremely unclear. Show the code for your controller actions and views.

Comment: you should remove this HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method call from your controller action.

Comment: with or without HttpUtility.HtmlEncode, it still throws the error.

Comment: what's the contents of your `gencomments.cshtml` custom editor template? On which line exactly are you getting the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you intending for the comments to specify the template name?  It looks like you are calling [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee407399.aspx) of EditorFor.

Try just

```
@Html.EditorFor(v => v.currentSite.gencomments, "gencomments")
```

To name the field, you can try this (no guarantees on this one though!):

```
@Html.EditorFor(v => v.currentSite.gencomments, "gencomments", "gencomments", null)
```

Comment: Ok thats weird, but it seems to have done the trick, however, now the name of that particular input box is currentsite.gencomments when I'd rather it just be gencomments, how do i do this

Comment: See my edit for how to name it- should work, but no guarantees.